# I am trying to run my XAMMP server on a different computer but I a am not able to

Tags: apache-http-server, xampp

I have tried modifying `httpd.conf` and `http-xampp.conf` to listen to my computer's IP address but it still doesn't seem to work. It is still listening on the localhost itself.

I have changed the server-name in httpd.conf to my local address as well as `listen`. In `httpd-xampp.conf` I have made the following change:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
        Require all granted
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried modifying httpd.conf and http-xampp.conf to listen to my computer's IP address but it still doesn't seem to work. It is still listening on the localhost itself.

The server will likely always respond on `localhost`. As a suggestion, your listen directive should be `Listen 80` (i.e. you do not need to put an IP address). Furthermore, there are likely only a few cases where the default `ServerName localhost:80` directive is likely to have any meaningful impact on your server.

> In httpd-xampp.conf I have made the following change[.]

It isn't clear to me from your question why you believe this might help your connection issues.